# Capturing stdout in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, stdout, nslog

I am using C in Objective C and I want to capture `stdout` to `UIView` from Console.
Here is the line I'm talking about:

```
print(stdout, v=toplevel_eval(v));
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than you are writing in C I have no idea how much you know about C, "Unix" and Cocoa I/O - so some of this you may already know.

Here is one possible solution, it looks more complicated than it is.

Reading:

- You need to understand the system calls [`pipe`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/pipe.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/pipe), [`dup2`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/dup2.2.html) and [`read`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/read.2.html).
- You need to understand the GCD function [`dispatch_async`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html) and how to obtain a GCD queue.
- `pipe` and `dup2` are often used in conjunction with `fork` and `exec` to launch a process and write/read to/from that process standard input/output. What you will be doing uses some of the same basic ideas so looking up examples of this common pattern will help you understand how these calls work. Here are some notes from a University: [Pipe, Fork, Exec and Related Topics](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/pipeforkexec.html).

Outline:

Using `dispatch_async` schedule a block to handle the reading and writing of the data. The block will:

1. Use `pipe` To create a pipe and `dup2` To connect stdout - file descriptor 1 - it.
2. Enter a loop which uses `read` to obtain the available data from the pipe. Data read will be in a byte array.
3. Within the loop convert the read bytes into an `NSString`
4. Within the loop append that string to your view - you **must** do this on the main thread as it involves the UI, and you can do that using another `dispatch_async` specifying the main queue.

That is it. Your block will now execute concurrently in the background reading whatever your C code writes to the standard output and adding it to your view.

If you get stuck you can ask a new question showing the code you have written and describing what doesn't work.

HTH